# JW Player : video play in mobile browser and web browser

Tags: jquery, html, flash, jwplayer

I am using **JW Player** to play videos in mobile and web browser;
I have many 100 videos with dimension **1280*700** px. This video fit for web browser and loading time according to web browser and net speed. this is fine.

Now if i want to play this same video in a mobile browser then the size of video will effect in loading to play. Because it is mobile not a computer.

Is this good approach to play same video in mobile and web. 
Or any solution please.

Should i use different videos for mobile and web browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use multiple resolutions.

An example like this would suffice - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29248/sd-and-hd-qualities

```
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      playlist: [{
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
        sources: [{
          file: "/uploads/myVideo360.mp4",
          label: "360p SD"
        },{
          file: "/uploads/myVideo720mp4",
          label: "720p HD"
        }]
      }]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sir thankx for your kind suggestion and ans.. I am not understanding what you are saying. my question is still not getting clear ans.

Comment: ok i will use multiple resolution. Which are the perfect sizes.

Comment: It really depends on what your user case is?

Comment: ok sir thankx .. is  640x360 pixels perfect for mobile an web width full screen..